# problemas al llamar un archivo php desde ajax con cordova

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, apache-cordova

estoy usando cordova, el problema es que paso datos de un formulario para enviarlo a un archivo php estoy usando ajax, pero cuando quiero recuperar mi print me aparece error 404 y no puedo solucionarlo.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../controlador/login.php',
    data: parametros,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#resultado").html('cargando..');

    },
    success: function (response) { 
        $("#resultado").html(response);
        $('#nombre').val('');
            $('#nick').val('');
            $('#nombre').val('');
            $('#apellido').val(''); 
            $('#correo').val('');
            $('#password').val('');   
    }
});
```

Lo siguiente es de mi php que quiero recuperar los datos y mostrarlos

```
<?php
  $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
  $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
  $correo = $_POST["correo"];
  $nick = $_POST["nick"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];
  print($nombre);
  ?>
```

el error que muestra es: jquery-3.6.0.js:10109 POST http://localhost:8000/controlador/login.php 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

- Verificá que la página a la que direccionás existe.
- Mirá si el enlace está mal escrito, por eso obtenés un error 404.
- Verificá los niveles a las que accedés a login.php

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "controlador/login.php",
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#resultado").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
            $("#resultado").html(datos);
            $('#guardar').attr("disabled", false);
            load(1);
          }
    });
```

Comment: hola, intente probar de distinta forma las Urls y aun me sale el mismo error, no se si es un problema con cordova ya que si lo aplico en php puro funciona pero en cordova no

Comment: Podría ser, ya que PHP se ejecuta en el lado del servidor, Cordova empaqueta la aplicación del lado del cliente.